# systemd shutdown action

Tags: shutdown, reboot, systemd

How can I use `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` folder for executing some action on shutdown or reboot in Ubuntu 15.10 ?

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in  

  reboot|poweroff)
       some command ;;

esac
```

This supposed to work (`/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` is working in this way) but it is not why ?